# How can 404 errors in requests to laravel dynamic subdirectory be fixed?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, directory, http-status-code-404, vesta

How can 404 errors in requests to laravel dynamic subdirectory be fixed?

Vesta cp creates a different directory to hold nginx web content than default nginx.

The different directory is:
`/home/user/web/somesite.com/public_html`

The normal default nginx directory is:
`/var/www/somesite.com/html`

The nginx configuration can be edited to change the root directory from `public_html` to the laravel root directory `public`, in this file:
`/home/user/conf/web/somesite.com.nginx.conf`

However, even after doing this, the orchid dashboard subdirectory `somesite.com/dashboard`, which is dynamically created by laravel, results in 404:

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could start by using `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to see the entire configuration that Nginx is using. Look for any `root` statement.

Comment: Thanks, this pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

Run `nginx -T` (uppercase T) // to list all of nginx configurations.

Then set the correct root in the nginx.conf, ie:
`/home/user/web/example.com/public;`

To fix these 404s, add this to the  `/home/user/conf/web/example.com.nginx.conf`:

```
location / {

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
...
```